# How to exclude rules of Analyzer?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have found that we can use `spark.sql.optimizer.excludedRules` to exclude rules in optimizer.
I want to known is there any config to exclude rules in analyzer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such a configuration property.

I think there's no way but to write your own `Analyzer`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a link for spark configuration documentation.
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html
I don't think you can exclude analyzer rules.